# Node.js + Cheerio : Request inside a loop

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm using cheerio, request and Node.js.

When I run the script below, it outputs names in a wrong order. I believe that it's caused by asynchronous nature of it, how can I make it work in the "right" order? Do I need to use a sync package or is there a way to change it in a way so it'll work in a sync way?

```
app.get('/returned', function (req, res) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        var url = "http://example.com" + y + "/person.html";
        request(url, function (err, resp, body) {
            $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var links = $('#container');
            var name = links.find('span[itemprop="name"]').html(); // name
            if (name == null) {
                console.log("returned null");
            } else {
                console.log(name);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: it depends. Do you want to send the requests in parallel, or in series. In series would be far slower than in parallel, assuming the server you're requesting from can handle more than 1 request at a time. It is possible to process it in parallel while still having the results in the order that you want.

Comment: In parallel. I think async will do the job (answered by @dm03514), I'll look into it.

Comment: note that his answer works in series, not parallel. but async does have a parallel option, you would just need to somehow store the results in the order that you want, regardless of the fact that they will be called out of order.

Comment: Why are you using app.get in the beginning? I'm trying to do something very similar working from this example, but I'm really stuck! Have read the request github docs, but it's not helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Promise makes this relatively easy:

```
app.get('/returned', function (req, res) {
    let urls = [];
    for (let y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        urls.push('http://example.com' + y + '/person.html');
    }
    Promise.all(urls.map(function (url) {
        return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
            request(url, function (err, resp, body) {
                if (err) {return reject(err);}
                let $ = cheerio.load(body);
                let links = $('#container');
                let name = links.find('span[itemprop="name"]').html(); // name
                resolve({name: name, links: links, url: url});
            });
        });
    }).then(function (result) {
        result.forEach(function (obj) {
            if (obj.name == null) {
                console.log(obj.url, "returned null");
            } else {
                console.log(obj.url, obj.name);
            }
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

I started by creating an array of urls to get, then I mapped that to an array of promises. When each of the requests are complete, i resolved the promise with the name, url, and links. When all promises were complete, I then looped over the result which will will be in the original order. This runs in parallel.

Comment: What does "app.get('/returned',..." do? Is this a directory specific to this example? I'm trying to recreate something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you shouldn't have to use a sync package. IMO the cleanest way is to use a mature 3rd party library.

I'd recommend async.

The `async.series` method would execute all request functions in the order they are given, then allow you to register a callback to fire when all requests have been made, or when an error has occurred.

https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback