# Running a request inside of a request (Node & Cheerio)

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

I am building a web scraper that uses node, request, and cheerio.

The function I have written takes a number as a parameter that gets used as an index in a for loop, and then each number in the loop corresponds to a url on a website that contains an index of blog posts. From there the function returns the title of every blog post on on each url, the href contained in each post title, and then another request is ran that returns every href contained on each individual posts page, using the href of the corresponding post title as an input value. So my output in the terminal should be formatted like this:

```
Title: Some Blog Post Title 1
Link: Some Blog Post Link 1
Blog Post Links: List of Links on Blogs Page 1
Title: Some Blog Post Title 2 
Link: Some Blog Post Link 2
Blog Post Links: List of Links on Blogs Page 2
```

But instead it is coming out like this:

```
Title: Some Blog Post Title 1
Link: Some Blog Post Link 1
Title: Some Blog Post Title 2 
Link: Some Blog Post Link 2
Giant list of blog post links
```

So my code is functional in that it retrieves all of the correct information for me, but it is not in the right format. The current output isn't helpful for me because I need to be able to tell which links correspond to each page rather than a giant list of links.
I have researched my problem and I'm pretty sure that this is happening because of the asynchronous nature of the code. My function is very similar to the question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506986/node-js-cheerio-request-inside-a-loop) but mine is different in the sense that there is a second request being ran using the output from the first request as an input in addition to the loop.
So my question is how to reformat my code to get my output to return in the desired order?

```
function scrapeUrls(num) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= num ; i++) {
            request(`https://www.website.com/blog?page=${i}`, (error, response, html) => {
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                const $ = cheerio.load(html);

                $('.group-right').each((i, el) => {
                    const articleTitle = $(el)
                        .find('h2')
                        .text();

                    const articleLink = $(el)
                        .find('a')  
                        .attr('href');
                    
       
                    console.log(`Title: ${articleTitle}\nLink: ${articleLink}\nBlog Post Links:`)

                    request(`https://www.website.com/${articleLink}`, (error, response, html) => {
                        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
                            $('.main-container').each((i) => {
                                    links = $('a');
                                    $(links).each(function(i, link) {
                                    console.log($(link).text() + ':\n ' + $(link).attr('href'));
                                })
                            })
                            
                        }
                    })
                });
            }
        })
    }      
}
```

Comment: Request is depreciated as of February 2020. The reason for this is because it is not current with the asynchronous nature/direction of Javascript. The reason your items are appearing in the wrong order is because some take longer to retrieve than others. Request can't help you with that, but there are alternatives like Got, or Fetch, etc., that can depending on your preference.

Answer (score 1):

As @Dshiz pointed out you need to `await` the promise if you want to keep the order. I suggest you use `node-fetch` instead of `request` which returns actual promise to be `awaited`:

```
let cheerio = require('cheerio');
let fetch = require('node-fetch');

function getArticlesLinks(html) {
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  let articles = [];
  $(".group-right").each((i, el) => {
    const articleTitle = $(el).find("h2").text();
    const articleLink = $(el).find("a").attr("href");
    console.log(`Title: ${articleTitle}\nLink: ${articleLink}\nBlog Post Links:`);
    articles.push(articleLink);
  });
  return articles;
}

function getLinks(html) {
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  $(".main-container").each((i) => {
    links = $("a");
    $(links).each(function (i, link) {
      console.log(
        $(link).text() + ":\n " + $(link).attr("href")
      );
    });
  });
}

async function scrapeUrls(num) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    // Fetch the page
    let pageResponse = await fetch(`https://www.website.com/blog?page=${i}`);
    if (pageResponse.ok) {
        let pageHtml = await pageResponse.text();
                    // ^ HERE
        // Extract articles' links
        let articles = getArticlesLinks(pageHtml);
        // For each article fetch and extract links
        for (let a of articles) {
          let articleResponse = await fetch(`https://www.website.com/${a}`);
          if (articleResponse.ok) {
            let articleHtml = await articleResponse.text();
                           // ^ HERE
            getLinks(articleHtml);
          }
        }
    }
  }
}


scrapeUrls(4)
  .then(() => console.log('done'))
  .catch(console.error)
```

Here I turned the `scrapeUrls` function into `async` so I can `await` inside each `for of` loop.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed response. While the explanation's of async functions in the code were very helpful, unfortunately the output is still coming out in the same order as before.

Comment: @paul-schultz, the url in your question doesn't even have a `.group-righ` element. If you provide your actual url it'll be easier to help.

Comment: The URL is for an organization I'm volunteering for so I didn't want to post it on here, they want me to go through their blog and embed youtube videos where they have links bc whoever wrote the blog posts didnt know how to do it hahaha. So I built the scraper to look through the posts for me. I'm just taking the output from the console and copying it into a Google doc then searching for instances of youtube manually since most of the heavy lifting is already done for me. Thanks for the help m8